# How can I create queryset with filter ManyToMany?

Tags: django

```
    class Box(models.Model):
        item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
        my_custom_item = models.ManyToManyField(Item)
```

This is incorrect:

```
i = Item.objects.get(id=1)
b = Box.objects.filter(my_custom_item=i)
```

How can I create queryset with filter ManyToMany?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`__in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in) expression as

```
b = Box.objects.filter(my_custom_item__id__in=[i,])
```

Answer (score 0):

In just one query:

```
b = Box.objects.filter(my_custom_item__id=1)
```